# How to display a calculation from user input in android studio

Tags: android

I am using android studio & want to create an app that allows me to calculate metal object weights.  I know the formula but not how to apply it with user input.

I am only thinking on tubes at present so the user adds the outside diameter, inside diameter & length.

I would like to know where to put the code & how to make a calculation based on this user input by them clicking on a button.

My current code is as follows

```
    package com.example.nealu.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

public void onAddClick(View a) {
if(a.getId() == R.id.editText)
}
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if Im not making sense!!

All help greatly appreciated cant find quote what I need searching around

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: I am trying to get 3 instances of user input to go into a calculation, which then displays an answer.  I want them to input 3 numbers, & those numbers would then go into a formula, & then show the answer.  Im not sure how to take the user input & run them through a calculation which is then displayed?

Comment: I think I got it. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. From your answer, you simply want to have three fields to input some data and make some calculations.

First, create your xml layout file. In my example it'll look something like this:

[image: Screen example]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculation"
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_input1"
        android:hint="Input 1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_input2"
        android:hint="Input 2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_input3"
        android:hint="Input 3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:id="@+id/bt_calculate"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/tv_result"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, on your `MainActivity.java`, get those inputs, make your calculations, and display the result.

**MainActivity.java**

```
// Imports and other stuff...
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText input1;
    private EditText input2;
    private EditText input3;

    private TextView tv_result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input1);
        input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input2);
        input3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_input3);

        Button bt_calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_calculate);

        tv_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);

        bt_calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                makeCalculations();
            }
        });
    }

    private void makeCalculations() {
        // I'm assuming you're getting numbers.
        double n1 = Double.valueOf(input1.getText().toString());
        double n2 = Double.valueOf(input2.getText().toString());
        double n3 = Double.valueOf(input3.getText().toString());

        // Do your calculation here.
        // I'm assuming you have inserted the result on a variable called 'result'. Like: double result 

        tv_result.setText("The result is: " + result);
    }

    // The rest of your Activity and methods.

}
```

After the user presses the `Button`, the result will appear on the bottom of the screen. Something like the image below.

[image: Result]

Comment: I can not appreciate your answer enough.  Thank you for this been melting my mind.